# MYSQL time diff

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate time diff between two time fields. Because the fields are just time with no date, I can't use `timestampdiff`, so I'm using `timediff()` or `subtime()`. The only problem with those is when the second time is less than the first time, it returns a negative `timediff` for me. I understand it's taking the times as the same day times, but is there any way to get a behavior where it always calculates the time forward? For example, I have 23:00:00 and 07:00:00. 
`timediff('07:00:00','23:00:00')` will return a negative value, because 23:00 is greater than 07:00, but I want to get 8 hours as the return. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with an if statement:

```
select if(dateA > dateB,
          timediff(dateA, dateB),
          addtime(timediff(dateA, dateB), '24:00:00.000000'))
```

This way, if the first date is smaller than the second, you add 24 hours to the difference.